# Using SAX Parsing to parse XML having nested elements

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing, sax

Consider the following example -

```
<a>abc</a>
<a>
    <a>bcd</a>
</a>
<a>
    <b>
        <a>
            <a>
                 def
            </a>
        </a>
    </b>
</a>
```

we have to do different thing when we meet an element `<a>` if it is a child node of another a or b element, and we have to different thing when we meet `<a>` as direct
child of root element.

How to process this file with SAX parsers?

Kindly explain.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with "SAX parsers" but if you can use Xpath to identify the nodes you want to process, then this will test whether the `<a>` node is a child of an `a` or `b`:

```
a[parent::*[self::a or self::b]]
```

If this is a valid XML document, I assume there is a root element with a name, and since you haven't illustrated it here, I'll give an example based on the assumption that it is called "root-element". In which case this will return true if `<a>` is its direct child:

```
a[parent::root-element]
```

There are probably other ways of achieving this depending on whether you're using Xpath 2 or not, but I think this should work in all cases. I hope that helps - if not, give more details of the exact environment you're using and I'm sure someone will be able to provide more precise help.